# Why Finnish hyphenation doesn't work correctly with words starting with "laus"?

Tags: hyphenation

With Finnish hyphenation turned on it seems that words starting with "laus" are not hyphenated at the first possible point. Here is example code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{testhyphens}
\setmainlanguage{finnish}

\begin{document}

\begin{checkhyphens}
  lause lausua lausun lausutte lauta laukaus laulaa lauma Laura
\end{checkhyphens}

\end{document}
```

It prints these:

```
lause
lausua
lausun
lausut-te
lau-ta
lau-kaus
lau-laa
lau-ma
Lau-ra
```

Normal Finnish hyphenating rules (outside Latex) would hyphenate the first four words like this: lau-se, lau-sua, lau-sun, lau-sut-te.

Comment: *Why*-type questions about LaTeX packages should be addressed to their maintainers.

Comment: I found file /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyph-utf8/patterns/tex/hyph-fi.tex which has line `u2s % estaa virheita yhdyssanojen yhteydessa` (translation: prevents errors with compound words). Maybe it prevents hyphenation between "u" and "s".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you’ve found, the relevant pattern is `u2s` that overrides the pattern `1se`, which would otherwise allow the hyphenation lau-se.  The patterns for Finnish are mostly implementing straightforward orthographic rules, with only a few at the end trying to deal with compound words (`u2s` followed by 42 more).  They can certainly be improved since they’re over thirty years old.  In the case of `u2s`, a cursory look at a word list suggests that this particular inhibiting pattern is preventing more good breaks than bad ones; I suppose it was felt to be better than the alternative of allowing bad breaks for the sake of some good ones, and nobody had the time to refine the patterns.

If you have the time, we can prepare an update to the current patterns.  I’ll also contact the original pattern author to see if he has suggestions.

Comment: Thank you. Finnish hyphenation is quite simple and everybody understands it well. The rules don't work over compound words but everybody knows that too and can put `\-` between some words.

The problem with current (La)tex hyphenation is that it tries to fix some problems with compound words and then causes unexpected behaviour elsewhere. Those new problems are more difficult to understand. If I had my way I would have just basic Finnish hyphenation rules without "clever" things.

Comment: Can you describe these new problems?  With the current pattern set you’ll have suboptimal hyphenation like ava-ruusai-ka; if you removed `u2s` you’d have the wrong hyphenation ava-ruu-sai-ka.  In both cases you can fix it with `\-`.

Comment: By new problems I mean unexpected behaviour: there's a hidden rule which works against what I know about Finnish hyphenation. I know that "avaruus\-aika" needs that hint but I might not know that "lau\-se" needs too. Somewhere there is also a hidden rule that creates "kon-kreettinen" and "demo-kratia". They have an etymological rationale but it's still allowed and very common to hyphenate those with basic rules: "konk-reettinen", "demok-ratia". I would prefer the basic easy rule by default.

Comment: Are these “basic rules” explained anywhere?

Comment: Can't find a description in English (yet). There are ten types of syllables: K=consonant, V=vowel. KV, KVK, KVV, KVVK, KVKK, V, VK, VV, VVK, VKK. In addition to that in the beginning of a word there can be also upto three K's. Diphthongs are: ai, au, ie, ei, eu, uo, oi, iu, yö, ui, ou, ey, yi, äy, iy, äi, öy, öi. That's the basic. Some diphthongs appear only in the first syllable.

Comment: Thanks.  A description in Finnish is fine, do you have a link?

Comment: Here: http://www.kielitoimistonohjepankki.fi/haku/tavutus/ohje/153 It would be great if there was an easily selectable "Finnish-basic" variant for hyphenation. I'm willing to help but maybe some mailing list is better place for this. Currently I don't know Tex hyphenation technically.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106168/discussion-between-arthur-reutenauer-and-dtw).